# Why can I not register this C# assembly for a U-SQL Project?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, u-sql

I have a U-SQL project that is referring to a C# project. It contains functions that are nothing special. The U-SQL is able to submit to Azure without any problems, but I get this message when I try to register my C# assembly.

My steps are:

- Clean C# Project
- Build C# Project
- Right Click-> Register Assembly
- Get this screen:
  [image]

The Text says "Not Ready to submit registration". I've restarted VS 2017 multiple times, and my computer. I've signed into my account for azure multiple times.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer: Apparently it was on VS 2015 not VS 2017. The 2015 plugin for Data Lake Analytics was outdated. We updated, and that was our solution.